# Pandas : New rows based on existing rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` with the following structure : `dataId, nodeId, tickDatetime`

This dataset represent the time (`tickDatetime`), where an element (`dataId`) pass through a node (`nodeId`).

Here is an example :

```
           dataId    nodeId     tickDatetime
0          data-0   node-01             3000
1          data-0   node-02             5000    
2          data-1   node-02             4000    
3          data-1   node-01             6000    
4          data-0   node-01             8000    
5          data-0   node-00            10000    
...           ...       ...
```

From this dataframe, I want to create a new dataframe `routes` that would contains the sequence of nodes and travel times for each `dataId`.

So I did the following :

```
routes = df.sort_values('tickDatetime').groupby('dataId').agg({'nodeId':[lambda x: list(x)],'tickDatetime':lambda x: list(x)})

def datetimes_to_travel_times(datetimes):
    traveltimes = np.empty(len(datetimes))
    old_value = datetimes[0]
    traveltimes[0] = 0

    for i in range(1,len(datetimes)):
        traveltimes[i] = datetimes[i] - old_value
        old_value = datetimes[i]

    return traveltimes

routes['traveltimes'] = routes['tickDatetime'].apply(lambda row: datetimes_to_travel_times(row))
```

Which give me the expected output (maybe not the best way to do it ?) :

```
           dataId                              nodeId                tickDatetime           traveltimes
0          data-0   [node-01,node-02,node-01,node-00]      [3000,5000,8000,10000]    [0,2000,3000,2000]
1          data-1                   [node-02,node-01]                 [4000,6000]              [0,2000]
```

Now I want my routes to be splitted if the traveltime goes above et certain threshold.

For example, with a threshold of 3000, I would like my `routes` dataframe to look like this :

```
           dataId   routeId              nodeId    tickDatetime    traveltimes
0          data-0         0   [node-01,node-02]      [3000,5000]      [0,2000]
1          data-0         1   [node-01,node-00]     [8000,10000]      [0,2000]
2          data-1         0   [node-02,node-01]      [4000,6000]      [0,2000]
```

How can I achieve that using Pandas ?

---

EDIT :

I managed to resolve my problem :

```
def split_routes(row):
    threshold = 3000
    nodes = row['nodeId']
    traveltimes = row['traveltimes']

    rows = []
    route_id = 0
    route_nodes = []
    route_traveltimes = []
    for i in range(0, len(traveltimes)):
        if(traveltimes[i]<threshold):
            route_nodes.append(nodes[i])
            route_traveltimes.append(traveltimes[i])
        else : 
            # Route route_id completed, starting a new one
            row['route_id'] = route_id
            row['Reader'] = route_nodes
            row['traveltimes'] = route_traveltimes
            rows.append(row)
            route_id+=1
            route_nodes.append(nodes[i])
            route_traveltimes.append(0)  

    # Route route_id completed, starting a new one            
    row['route_id'] = route_id
    row['Reader'] = route_nodes
    row['traveltimes'] = route_traveltimes
    rows.append(row)

    return pd.DataFrame(rows)

splitted_routes_array = []
for index, row in routes.iterrows():
    splitted_routes_array.append(split_routes(row))

splitted_routes = pd.concat(splitted_routes_array)
```

Comment: `df.groubpy('dataId',as_index = False).agg(list)`

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'dataId':['data-0','data-0','data-1','data-1','data-0','data-0'],
'nodeId':['node-01','node-02','node-02','node-01','node-01','node-00'],
'tickDatetime':[3000,5000,4000,6000,8000,10000]})

append_ = lambda x:list(x)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2['nodeId'] = df.groupby('dataId')['nodeId'].apply(append_)
df_2['tickDatetime'] = df.groupby('dataId')['tickDatetime'].apply(append_)
print(df_2)
```

Output:

```
                                  nodeId               tickDatetime
dataId                                                                 
data-0  [node-01, node-02, node-01, node-00]  [3000, 5000, 8000, 10000]
data-1                    [node-02, node-01]               [4000, 6000]
```

Comment: `df.groubpy('dataId',as_index = False).agg(list)` or `df.groubpy('dataId',as_index = False)[cols].agg(list)`